# Unity Android Build Issues

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, unity-editor

I am trying to build a project for Android and just seem to encounter endless stream of errors. I've completely removed the editors, re-installed, updated and still the same issues. All builds for iOS ok and runs in the editor without issue, but I am getting at least 5 errors like this:

```
Building Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/zqff_y-CSharp10.o failed with output:
Stack dump:
0.  Program arguments: /Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/2021.3.8f1/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/NDK/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/clang++ -cc1 -triple aarch64-unknown-linux-android22 -emit-obj -mnoexecstack -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -discard-value-names -main-file-name Assembly-CSharp10.cpp -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -mthread-model posix -masm-verbose -mconstructor-aliases -munwind-tables -fuse-init-array -target-cpu generic -target-feature +neon -target-abi aapcs -mllvm -aarch64-fix-cortex-a53-835769=1 -fallow-half-arguments-and-returns -dwarf-column-info -debug-info-kind=limited -dwarf-version=4 -debugger-tuning=gdb -target-linker-version 305 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -coverage-notes-file /Volumes/Projects/Projects/SampleProject/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/zqff_y-CSharp10.gcno -resource-dir /Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/2021.3.8f1/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/NDK/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/lib64/clang/9.0.8 -D __ANDROID_API__=22 -D ANDROID -D HAVE_INTTYPES_H -D BASELIB_INLINE_NAMESPACE=il2cpp_baselib -D IL2CPP_MONO_DEBUGGER_DISABLED -D RUNTIME_IL2CPP -D TARGET_ARM64 -D HAVE_BDWGC_GC -D NDEBUG -I . -I /Volumes/Projects/Projects/SampleProject/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp -I /Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/2021.3.8f1/Unity.app/Contents/il2cpp/libil2cpp/pch -I /Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/2021.3.8f1/Unity.app/Contents/il2cpp/libil2cpp -I /Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/2021.3.8f1/Unity.app/Contents/il2cpp/external/baselib/Include -I /Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/2021.3.8f1/Unity.app/Contents/il2cpp/external/baselib/Platforms/Android/Include -internal-isystem /Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/2021.3.8f1/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/NDK/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/../sysroot/usr/include/c++/v1 -internal-isystem /Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/2021.3.8f1/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/NDK/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/../sysroot/usr/local/include -internal-isystem /Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/2021.3.8f1/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/NDK/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/lib64/clang/9.0.8/include -internal-externc-isystem /Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/2021.3.8f1/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/NDK/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/../sysroot/usr/include/aarch64-linux-android -internal-externc-isystem /Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/2021.3.8f1/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/NDK/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/../sysroot/include -internal-externc-isystem /Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/2021.3.8f1/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/NDK/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/../sysroot/usr/include -Os -Wswitch -Wno-trigraphs -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-invalid-offsetof -Wno-implicitly-unsigned-literal -Wno-integer-overflow -Wno-shift-negative-value -Wno-unknown-attributes -Wno-implicit-function-declaration -Wno-null-conversion -Wno-missing-declarations -Wno-unused-value -Wno-pragma-once-outside-header -std=c++11 -fdeprecated-macro -fdebug-compilation-dir /Volumes/Projects/Projects/SampleProject -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 0 -fvisibility hidden -fwrapv -stack-protector 1 -fno-rtti -fno-signed-char -fobjc-runtime=gcc -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fdiagnostics-show-option -fdiagnostics-format msvc -fcolor-diagnostics -vectorize-loops -vectorize-slp -o Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/zqff_y-CSharp10.o -x c++ /Volumes/Projects/Projects/SampleProject/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Assembly-CSharp10.cpp 
1.  <eof> parser at end of file
2.  Code generation
3.  Running pass 'Function Pass Manager' on module '/Volumes/Projects/Projects/SampleProject/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Assembly-CSharp10.cpp'.
4.  Running pass 'CodeGen Prepare' on function '@GifEncoder_GetImagePixels_m5E81065BA3C89066FF3574388B659C8B3C47C0D6'
0  clang++                  0x00000001013e3f98 void std::__1::__call_once_proxy<std::__1::tuple<void (&)()> >(void*) + 452872
1  clang++                  0x00000001013e2fd8 void std::__1::__call_once_proxy<std::__1::tuple<void (&)()> >(void*) + 448840
2  clang++                  0x00000001013e45b9 void std::__1::__call_once_proxy<std::__1::tuple<void (&)()> >(void*) + 454441
3  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007ff803d40c1d _sigtramp + 29
4  clang++                  0x00000001009de54d llvm::Pass* llvm::callDefaultCtor<llvm::TargetTransformInfoWrapperPass>() + 9949
5  clang++                  0x0000000000000009 llvm::Pass* llvm::callDefaultCtor<llvm::TargetTransformInfoWrapperPass>() + 18446744069404246425
clang++: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11
clang++: error: clang frontend command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)
Android (6454773 based on r365631c2) clang version 9.0.8 (https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/llvm-project 98c855489587874b2a325e7a516b99d838599c6f) (based on LLVM 9.0.8svn)
Target: aarch64-unknown-linux-android22
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/2021.3.8f1/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/NDK/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin
clang++: note: diagnostic msg: PLEASE submit a bug report to https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/issues and include the crash backtrace, preprocessed source, and associated run script.
clang++: note: diagnostic msg: 
********************

PLEASE ATTACH THE FOLLOWING FILES TO THE BUG REPORT:
Preprocessed source(s) and associated run script(s) are located at:
clang++: note: diagnostic msg: /var/folders/5j/sbt09jjn3lz1ch1x_l5tlv5h0000gn/T/Assembly-CSharp10-667163.cpp
clang++: note: diagnostic msg: /var/folders/5j/sbt09jjn3lz1ch1x_l5tlv5h0000gn/T/Assembly-CSharp10-667163.sh
clang++: note: diagnostic msg: Crash backtrace is located in
clang++: note: diagnostic msg: /Users/SampleUser/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/clang++_<YYYY-MM-DD-HHMMSS>_<hostname>.crash
clang++: note: diagnostic msg: (choose the .crash file that corresponds to your crash)
clang++: note: diagnostic msg: 

********************
UnityEditor.BuildPipeline:BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions)
Google.Android.AppBundle.Editor.Internal.BuildTools.AndroidBuilder:Build (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions) (at Assets/GooglePlayPlugins/com.google.android.appbundle/Editor/Scripts/Internal/BuildTools/AndroidBuilder.cs:178)
Google.Android.AppBundle.Editor.Internal.BuildAndRunner:EmulateUnityBuildAndRun () (at Assets/GooglePlayPlugins/com.google.android.appbundle/Editor/Scripts/Internal/BuildAndRunner.cs:91)
Google.Android.AppBundle.Editor.Internal.BuildAndRunner:BuildAndRunDefault () (at Assets/GooglePlayPlugins/com.google.android.appbundle/Editor/Scripts/Internal/BuildAndRunner.cs:69)
Google.Android.AppBundle.Editor.Internal.BuildAndRunner:BuildAndRun () (at Assets/GooglePlayPlugins/com.google.android.appbundle/Editor/Scripts/Internal/BuildAndRunner.cs:53)
Google.Android.AppBundle.Editor.Internal.AppBundleEditorMenu:BuildAndRun () (at Assets/GooglePlayPlugins/com.google.android.appbundle/Editor/Scripts/Internal/AppBundleEditorMenu.cs:72)
```

I've tired downloading SDK/NDK via Android studio and pointing unity at those, and still get 5 - 10 of these error types.

Comment: Well, you should configure Unity through the Unity Hub, not try to install NDK on your own. Follow the steps here https://developer.android.com/games/develop/build-in-unity

Comment: I’ve used the sdk/ndk that Unity Hub installs, I’ve tried additional ones via Android Studio because straight out of the box I am getting these errors

Comment: Maybe uninstall everything and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Seems the only way I can get this to work for now is to export a project that can be opened by Android Studio.  It then builds and deploys without issue